# Match 2 sql columns if = then update a different column by 1

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking to see if there is a match between what someone submitted in one table to a different table in the database. 
I can't quite figure out how to set it up. What im trying for is

```
  IF tableA column A = tableB column B then table A column C = Column C + 1.
```

I have tried the update method but that seems to not be working for me. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: RTLM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: left join? inner join? is this psuedocode? what is your query? results? expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it would be this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a JOIN TABLE_B b 
  ON a.join_col = b.join_col AND a.column_a = b.column_b
SET a.column_c = a.column_c + 1
```

The `join_col` value is likely the user_id so that you only update rows in `TABLE_A` where that *same user* has the same value in `TABLE_B`.

Comment: thanks for submitting this. Im bout to run it now. let you know how it goes

Comment: You may need to tweak it for adding 1 to the value of column_c, unless column_c is an integer already. Sometimes type casting can be complicated.

Comment: I was curious if I had a third table if this could still work. I was reading up that using 3 joins of table in an UPDATE doesnt work? what i would like is UPDATE tablec JOIN tablea JOIN tableb

Comment: Good question about adding a 3rd table. I'm not really sure as I haven't tried it. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work tho -

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do this in mysql:

```
UPDATE TableA a, TableB b 
SET a.ColumnC = ColumnC + 1 
WHERE a.ColumnA = b.ColumnB;
```

Comment: This would update ALL rows in TableA where a.ColumnA = b.ColumnB -- even if they were from different users. In this case, it would update TableA if *any* user had their ColumnB equal to that user's ColumnA -- I believe the OP wants to only update ColumnC when for that specific user.

Comment: This code is transformation of presented pseudo code just to show the syntax, @Ricky can change it as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

if this is what you want

```
update tableA set colA=(select (case when b.colB=colA then colC+1 else colC end) from tableB b)
```

Comment: nope, this won't work for many reasons. even if it executed without error, it will update wrong column.