# How can I do three table JOINs in an UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, join

I asked a question and got this reply which helped.

```
   UPDATE TABLE_A a JOIN TABLE_B b
   ON a.join_col = b.join_col AND a.column_a = b.column_b
   SET a.column_c = a.column_c + 1
```

Now I am looking to do this if there are three tables involved something like this.

```
    UPDATE tableC c JOIN tableB b JOIN tableA a
```

My question is basically... is it possible to do three table joins on an `UPDATE` statement? And what is the correct syntax for it?

Do I do the following?

```
 JOIN tableB, tableA
 JOIN tableB JOIN tableA
```

Comment: Sure it is possible. Give it a try.  The syntax is just like you have it -you just need to add the next `JOIN` and its `ON` condition, same as you would in a `SELECT` query.

Comment: `UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id SET t1.col = 'newval'`

Comment: The mentioned question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206746/match-2-sql-columns-if-then-update-a-different-column-by-1

Answer (score 863, accepted):

The answer is *yes*, you can.

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a
    JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.join_col = b.join_col AND a.column_a = b.column_b
    JOIN TABLE_C c ON [condition]
SET a.column_c = a.column_c + 1
```

For a general *update* join:

```
UPDATE TABLEA a
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Comment: Weird thing is however that my HeidiSQL software reports zero affected rows, although the data shows the updates were done.

Comment: @Pianoman To me it happened as well and it had something to do with ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I just added manually the update and it fixed it, just saying if it happens to anyone else

Comment: If you need a visual aid to get your joins correct: https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/mysql-joins-visual-representation

Comment: I think the following is a better General Plan: `UPDATE table A JOIN table B ON {join data} JOIN table C ON {join data} JOIN {more join tables} SET A.column = {expression}` (forgive me if this blasted editor won't let me enter newlines without doing a full post)

Comment: Where is `WHERE`?? Or `WHERE` is not possible?

Comment: @Green WHERE its almost like ON  here . ON is a condition .

Comment: @green WHERE comes last, after SET. echo_Me please add WHERE in your post, because later comments aren't shown.

Answer (score 49):

An alternative way of [achieving the same result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/740a7) is not to use the `JOIN` keyword at all.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A, TABLE_B
SET TABLE_A.column_c = TABLE_B.column_c + 1
WHERE TABLE_A.join_col = TABLE_B.join_col
```

Comment: I tried this on 5.5.62 and mysql didin't like the syntax. According to the manual [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html], the query should be: `UPDATE TABLE_A, TABLE_B SET TABLE_A.column_c = TABLE_A.column_c +1 WHERE TABLE_A.join_col = TABLE_B.join_col `

Comment: This does an implicit `JOIN` in the same way doing `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B ...` does

Comment: So does that mean that in 5.5 only implicit joins form is accepted for update?

Comment: @userfuser No, it doesn't, the manual states the syntax:
    `UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]`
Later on, the manual states: "The `table_references` clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described in [Section 13.2.9.2, JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)."

Comment: Not the exact same result -- you can do left joins with the join syntax.

Comment: Thanks. This worked but how would you sort the second table(table_b), so that the latest value of column_c is saved in table_a column_c.

Answer (score 13):

Below is the *update* query which includes both `JOIN` and `WHERE`. In the same way, we can use multiple join/where clauses:

```
UPDATE opportunities_cstm oc JOIN opportunities o ON oc.id_c = o.id
 SET oc.forecast_stage_c = 'APX'
 WHERE o.deleted = 0
   AND o.sales_stage IN('ABC','PQR','XYZ')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do a three-table join for an update statement. Here is an example:

```sql
UPDATE customer_table c

  JOIN
      employee_table e
      ON c.city_id = e.city_id
  JOIN
      anyother_table a
      ON a.someID = e.someID

SET c.active = "Yes"
WHERE c.city = "New york";
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative *general plan*:

```
UPDATE table A
JOIN table B ON {join fields}
JOIN table C ON {join fields}
JOIN {as many tables as you need}
SET A.column = {expression}
```

Example:

```
UPDATE person P
JOIN address A ON P.home_address_id = A.id
JOIN city C ON A.city_id = C.id
SET P.home_zip = C.zipcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a PostgreSQL example:

```
UPDATE TableA AS a
SET param_from_table_a=FALSE -- param FROM TableA
FROM TableB AS b
WHERE b.id=a.param_id AND a.amount <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

none of answer does not work for me I find this on mysql manual

```
UPDATE T1,T2 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 SET T1.C2 = T2.C2,       T2.C3 = expr WHERE condition
```