# SQL Update after Joining Two Tables

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL, using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I am trying to write a SQL statement that performs an update after two tables are joined.

I have two tables: `myTable1` and `myTable2`. Both share a field `MyID`, which is going to be the field that I join on. `myTable1` contains a column called `BitToUpdate`. And MyTable2 contains a column called `BitToCheck`.

I want to set `BitToUpdate` in `myTable1` to be 1 where `BitToCheck` in `myTable2` is 1 as well.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT M.MyID, BitToUpdate, BitToCheck
INTO #temp_table
FROM myTable1 as T1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 as T2
ON M.MyId = PO.MyId
```

So first I tried to join the two tables `myTable1` and `myTable2` on their IDs, and store the result in a temporary table.

Next, I want to update `BitToUpdate` to be 1 where `BitToCheck` is 1.

So to do that in the temporary table, I have:

```
UPDATE #temp_table
SET 
    `BitToUpdate` = 1
WHERE
    `BitToCheck` = 1
```

This updates the `BitToUpdate` successfully in #temp_table. However, when I do a select on `myTable1`, I find that `BitToUpdate` is not changed. I suppose this makes sense as #temp_table isn't really a "pointer"....

But what would be the correct way to approach this join and update?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't need to use a `LEFT JOIN` here, since you are checking on a condition from table 2, so an `INNER JOIN` should be better here.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.BitToUpdate = 1
FROM myTable1 T1
INNER JOIN myTable2 T2
    ON T1.MyId = T2.MyId
WHERE T2.BitToCheck = 1
```

Comment: This is wrong, please refer to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query

The order are:Update --> JOIN --> SET

Comment: In case someone cares: the query above is not wrong. In MS SQL you can do either UPDATE --> JOIN --> SET or UPDATE --> SET --> FROM --> JOIN ... or even UPDATE --> SET --> FROM --> WHERE...

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing in your first query is updating a temp table named `#temp`. the updates never go to the actual table `myTable1` or `mayTable2`. To update records while joining with other tables try this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.BitToUpdate = 1
FROM myTable1 as T1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 as T2 (ON T1.MyId = T2.MyId)
WHERE T2.BitToCheck = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--SELECT M.MyID, BitToUpdate, BitToCheck
--INTO #temp_table
update t1
  set t1.BitToUpdate = 1
FROM myTable1 as T1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 as T2
ON t1.MyId = t2.MyId
where t2.bittocheck = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T1
SET BitToUpdate=1
FROM myTable1 T1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 T2
ON T1.MyId=T2.MyId
WHERE T2.BitToCheck=1
```