# Update records in table from CTE results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the records in my table using CTE.
And I've been trying with the insert function using CTE and it's working. 
This is my query with the insert function:

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
    FROM DAILYDATA
)
INSERT INTO DAILYDATAWH (NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT)
SELECT  NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN = MIN(DATEATTEND), STATUSOUT = MAX(DATEATTEND)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, (RN - 1) / 2
```

How to change that with the update function?

i want to change to update function because when i use insert function,the previous data that already exists in `DAILYDATA` appear again

This is table `DAILYDATA`

[image: TABLE DAILYDATA]

This is table `DAILYDATAWH`

[image: TABLE DAILYDATAWH]

[image: error]

Comment: Well, what do you want updated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i want to Update `NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT`

Comment: Why are you calculating Row_Number in the UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to update table after joining like below

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
   FROM   DAILYDATA
)
Update your_table
SET -- your_table.columns = CTE.columns  
From your_table
Inner join CTE on your_condition_join_here
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[SQL Update after Joining Two Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481505/sql-update-after-joining-two-tables)

**Updated**

You should use multiple CTE in a query like below

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
FROM DAILYDATA
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, MIN(CTE.DATEATTEND) AS Min_DATEATTEND, MAX(CTE.DATEATTEND) AS Max_DATEATTEND
From CTE
GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT
)
Update DAILYDATAWH
SET DAILYDATAWH.NIP = CTE2.NIP ,
DAILYDATAWH.NAME = CTE2.NAME,
DAILYDATAWH.DEPARTMENT = CTE2.DEPARTMENT,
DAILYDATAWH.STATUSIN = CTE2.Min_DATEATTEND,
DAILYDATAWH.STATUSOUT = CTE2.Max_DATEATTEND
From DAILYDATA
Inner join CTE2 on DAILYDATA.NIP = CTE2.NIP
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, `; WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
   FROM   DAILYDATA
)
Update DAILYDATAWH
SET DAILYDATAWH.NIP = CTE.NIP , DAILYDATAWH.NAME = CTE.NAME, 
DAILYDATAWH.DEPARTMENT = CTE.DEPARTMENT, DAILYDATAWH.STATUSIN = MIN(CTE.DATEATTEND), DAILYDATAWH.STATUSOUT = MAX(CTE.DATEATTEND)
From DAILYDATA
Inner join CTE on DAILYDATAWH` i've been following your answer,but get an error in `on DAILYDATAWH`

Comment: what is 'your_condition_join_here', can you explain that an give an example?

Comment: your_condition_join_here = `your_table.column1 = CTE.column1`, `column1` often is primary key.

Comment: `on DAILYDATAWH.NIP = CTE.NIP` but still error in `DAILYDATAWH.NIP`

Comment: Capture an image full your code & error msg, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207955/discussion-between-phong-and-dea-ananda).

Answer (score 1):

You just use the CTE as if it were a table.  Your question is rather vague on what you want updated with the CTE, but the syntax is something like:

```
WITH TOUPDATE AS (
      SELECT DD.*,
             RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND)
      FROM DAILYDATA dd
     )
UPDATE TOUPDATE
    SET something = run;
```

Comment: i want to Update `NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT` like the value in insert function

Comment: @DeaAnanda . . . I might suggest that you ask a NEW question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you want to do.  This answers the question you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're calculating `row_number` but you might

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND),
    MIN(DATEATTEND) OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND) AS cteSTATUSIN,
    MAX(DATEATTEND) OVER (PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT ORDER BY DATEATTEND) AS cteSTATUSOUT
    FROM DAILYDATA
)
Update DAILYDATAWH
SET DAILYDATAWH.NIP = CTE.NIP , DAILYDATAWH.NAME = CTE.NAME,
DAILYDATAWH.DEPARTMENT = CTE.DEPARTMENT,
DAILYDATAWH.STATUSIN = cteSTATUSIN,
DAILYDATAWH.STATUSOUT = cteSTATUSOUT,
From DAILYDATA Inner join CTE on DAILYDATA.NIP = CTE.NIP
```