# Update join two tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I've in mysql db two tables:

1) dotable_new;

2) dotable_new_new

Now I need update the value TOTAL in my table dotable_new of value TOTAL in my table dotable_new_new.

I'm trying this update query without success ... can you help me?

```
UPDATE dotable_new a, dotable_new_new tmp
SET a.total = tmp.total
WHERE
    a.rdt IN ('tot mac')
```

dotable_new;

```
+---------+---------------+--------+-------+----+
| RDT     | TYPE          | NUMBER | TOTAL | ID |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------+----+
| tot mac | tot           |   3209 |  3249 |  1 |
+---------+---------------+--------+-------+----+
```

dotable_new_new

```
+---------+-------+----+
| RDT     | TOTAL | ID |
+---------+-------+----+
| tot mac | 10899 |  5 |
+---------+-------+----+
```

Comment: The `a.rdt IN ()` returns multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this will help you on [how to join two tables in update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join/15209489#15209489)

try that:

```
  UPDATE dotable_new a
  INNER JOIN dotable_new_new tmp ON tmp.rdt = a.rdt
  SET a.total =  tmp.total
  WHERE a.rdt = 'tot mac'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dotable_new a
SET a.total = (SELECT tmp.total
               FROM  dotable_new_new tmp
               WHERE tmp.rdt = a.rdt)
```

If you want to update the record `rdt = 'tot mac'` only, then add the following line to the end:

```
WHERE a.rdt = 'tot mac'
```