# Update statements with joins SQL, PHP

Tags: php, sql

Practicing some PHP with Databases and I have come across a bit of a problem.

My code for viewing multiple tables and printing is the following and works great.

```
"SELECT g.id AS golf_id, g.sname AS golf_name, g.start AS start, a.sname AS alpha_name FROM golf AS g, alpha AS a WHERE g.act=a.id) as $a)
```

However, I am now trying to make it so that I can edit and also insert entries to the tables via the web page.

But I am having trouble getting it to work with my joins and that.

Here is the SQL part.. with what is currently working (only 1 table -no joins)

```
$sql = 'UPDATE golf SET sname=:sname, start=:start
WHERE id=:id';
```

Where id=:id is used because when you click on the hyperlink you want to edit, the id code is the page and that's how it knows to edit that specific item.

How would I edit that statement to include the following joins from the first statement?

Appreciate any ideas greatly.

Comment: There is a mess with braces

Comment: It's probably possible, but you don't even want that. Just write separate update statements for each table.

Comment: You don't need to a join for that update unless sname is in table alpha? If so two update statements like @popovitsj said

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific update you're trying to perform?

Comment: Try checking out this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join

Comment: I'll try two separate UPDATE Statements, I'm assuming you could also do separate INSERT statements aswell for the same problem? Thanks for the help and link.