# Error in inner join update sql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. In one table I have id and in another I have userId. This is the only connection between them.

Problem is: In one table I have username and in another I have his balance. I want to get user's balance according to his username. Since there is only one column which is connecting them and it is ID, I need to find a way how to update users balance if I have only his username.

Here is what I have tried but it is not working:

```
  UPDATE t1
  SET t1.balance = '999'
  FROM bitcoin.accountbalance AS t1
  INNER JOIN bitcoin.webusers AS t2
  ON t1.userId = t2.id
  WHERE t2.username = 'simpanz';
```

EDIT:

```
ERROR IS: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM bitcoin.accountbalance AS t1   INNER JOIN bitcoin.webusers AS t2     WHERE ' at line 3
```

I use MySQL.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in both SQL Server and MySQL:

```
UPDATE accountbalance
  SET balance = '999'
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM webusers
                WHERE webusers.id = accountbalance.userId AND
                      webusers.username = 'simpanz'
               );
```

Comment: This shows this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.balance' in 'field list'

Comment: @OndrejTokar . . . That needs to go anyway.  SQL Server doesn't like table aliases in `set` statements.

Comment: This was the answer: UPDATE accountbalance
  SET balance = '999999'
  WHERE userId = (SELECT id
                FROM webusers
                WHERE username = 'simpanz'
               );
Since you were the closest cn you edit your answer so I can mark it as the right? Thank you.

Comment: @OndrejTokar . . . That answer should be equivalent to what is in the answer.  What is the issue with the `exists` version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 UPDATE  bitcoin.accountbalance AS t1

 INNER JOIN bitcoin.webusers AS t2
 ON t1.userId = t2.id
 SET t1.balance = '999'
 WHERE t2.username = 'simpanz';
```

you have to join tables and then SET what you want.

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join/15209489#15209489)

Comment: sorry it was mistake , try now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL try this and let me know if it works:

```
UPDATE bitcoin.accountbalance t1
INNER JOIN bitcoin.webusers t2
ON t1.userId = t2.id
SET t1.balance = '999'
WHERE t2.username = 'simpanz';
```