# Database challenge: How to Update 1 million records efficiently?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I am struggling to update my massive database but my wamp/Heidisql keeps crashing due to this large update/comparisons.

I have two database tables: main table "member_all" (contains 3 million records) and child table:"mobile_results" (contains 9,000 records). The database structure of tables look like this:

**Main Table ("member_all")**

```
id int(11),
name varchar(255),
phoneWork varchar(255),
phoneMobile  varchar(255),
phoneMobileNetwork varchar(255)
```

***Data in table*** looks like this:

```
id name      phoneWork      phoneMobile   phoneMobileNetwork 
1  bill      061090999990   0789867676    Null
3  billsaasa 06109094399990 076689867676  Null
```

**Child Table : ("mobile_results")**

```
id int(11) autoincrement,
phoneMobile varchar(255),
phoneMobileNetwork  varchar(255)
```

Data in mobile_results looks like this:

```
id     phoneMobile  phoneMobileNetwork
8789   0789867676   Orange     
238789 076689867676 O2
```

All my mobile network data for 9,000 mobile number is stored in "mobile_results" but when i try to compare both these table ,i get stuck and my wamp/Heidi sql crashes?

**My question is :**

How can i populate "member_all" with "phoneMobileNetwork" values from "mobile_results" efficiently?

Here are the queries i have tried:

**Query 1**

i divided my query using limit .This is slow and would also take 1 week to compare 9,000 records from mobile_results.

```
update  member_all,mobile_results 
set member_all.phoneMobileNetwork=mobile_results.phoneMobileNetwork  
where member_all.phoneMobile in  
(SELECT phoneMobile FROM mobile_results limit 1,10);
```

**Query 2**

```
update  member_all,mobile_results 
set member_all.phoneMobileNetwork=mobile_results.phoneMobileNetwork  
where member_all.phoneMobile in  
(SELECT phoneMobile FROM mobile_results where id <10);
```

Same not good for large number of records.

PLEASE help me how can i update records my "member_all" table efficiently in one go.

I would appreciate you help in this regard.

Comment: wow, inefficient use of space. I'd reduce the size of your varchar's...nothing to do with your question though, sorry.

Comment: What exactly does "i get stuck and my wamp/Heidi sql crashes" mean? What error do you receive?

Comment: @MartinK.my HeidiSQL/phpmyadmin stops responding.

Comment: @user3489398 :For further reference. Please make sure you format the question so that the people that are helping you see what you are asking

Comment: @Arion.Thanks arion.i will keep this thing in mind

Comment: You looking for a MySQL-specific or Oracle-specific answer?  You seem to be referring to MySQL, but you have an 'Oracle' tag.  The answer is likely to be substantially different.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `phoneMobile` in both tables? If you don't, you should.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you need to do it often? Based on that I can recommend some approaches that could be very fast. Also if it is MySQL, what engine are you using and how do you have MySQL configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try joing the tables on the update. No `EXISTS`, no `IN`. Like this:

```
update member_all AS ma
  JOIN mobile_results ms on ma.phoneMobile=ms.phoneMobile
  SET member_all.phoneMobileNetwork=mobile_results.phoneMobileNetwork
```

Reference:

- [mysql update join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try this.I think using Exist will be faster

```
update  member_all
set phoneMobileNetwork=
(select phoneMobileNetwork  from mobile_results where 
member_all.phoneMobile=mobile_results.phoneMobile)
WHERE EXISTS
(
select 1 from mobile_results where 
member_all.phoneMobile=mobile_results.phoneMobile);
```