# simple mysql update statements hangs on large database

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

```
update temp_parent_rating_emails pre
set reminders_count = (select count(1) from vendor_rating_email vre where vre.parent_email_id = pre.email_id);
```

the above query runs fine on my small mysql database but hangs on our larger staging database. anyone know why or how to better optimize this?

Comment: Is there an index on vendor_rating_email table on the parent_email_id column?  That would be my first guess.

Comment: you're running a correlated subquery, which means the subquery runs once for every row in the parent table. painful when it's a large db...

Comment: @marcB thanks, i checked the wiki page and it suggested to create a view. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an index if there isn't one already

```
ALTER TABLE vendor_rating_email ADD INDEX (parent_email_id) ;
```

and then see if your query runs faster.  Much of the time if you have a query that runs fast on a small database and slow on a large database, there is need for an index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a sub-query, try an inline view, as below, so that the `vendor_rating_email` table is scanned only once.

```
update temp_parent_rating_emails pre
    JOIN
    (
        select 
            parent_email_id,
            count(*) cnt_email
        from vendor_rating_email
        group by parent_email_id
    ) vre ON  vre.parent_email_id = pre.email_id
SET pre.reminders_count = vre.cnt_email;
```

Also, consider creating indexes on `temp_parent_rating_emails (parent_email_id)` and `vendor_rating_email (email_id)`.

**Reference**:

[mysql update join on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Comment: i tried this query but i killed it after 40mins. wikipedia says to create a view to optimize the subquery: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery so i am trying that now.

Comment: Unless you create materialized views (not available in MySQL), you still run the query when you access the view. The key is to create proper indexes as well.

Comment: @peter Do you have indexes on temp_parent_rating_emails.parent_email_id and vendor_rating_email.email_id?