# MySQL syntax for update with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with the following structure:

**Table User**

- id
- name
- points

**Table Group**

- id
- name
- group_score

**Table UsersGroups (association table)**

- UserId
- GroupId

I'm trying to calculate the group_score - simply through adding all points of the users inside the group - for all groups.

i tried the following query

```
UPDATE `Group` SET group_score = (SELECT SUM(User.points) FROM User
                                    JOIN UsersGroups
                                    ON User.id = UsersGroups.UserId
                                    GROUP BY UsersGroups.GroupId)
```

which gives me OperationalError ('Subquery returns more than 1 row')

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql update join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Comment: Is this user in more than one group?

Comment: Calling a table 'group' is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Milen Pavlov: Yes, users can be in more than one group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Group` JOIN (SELECT GroupId, SUM(User.points) as sumuser FROM User
                                    JOIN UsersGroups
                                    ON User.id = UsersGroups.UserId
                                    GROUP BY UsersGroups.GroupId) x
ON `Group`.Id=x.GroupId
SET group_score =x.sumuser
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE `Group` SET group_score = (SELECT UsersGroups.GroupId SUM(User.points) FROM User
                                    JOIN UsersGroups
                                    ON User.id = UsersGroups.UserId
                                    GROUP BY UsersGroups.GroupId)
```