# MySql: Update more than one column

Tags: php, mysql

**My timetable table looks like this:**

```
  id  period   mon   mon_tch   tue   tue_tch   wed   wed_tch
  --  ------   ---   -------   ---   -------   ---   -------
   1   prd1     4       5       8        7      6       3    
   2   prd2     6       3       4        5      8       7
```

**My teacher-subject table:**

```
   id   tchr   subject
   --   ----   -------
    1     5       4
    2     7       8
```

where values in `mon` is the subject_id and `mon_tch` is the `teacher_id` and so on.

When admin changes the subject of a teacher in the 'teacher-subject' table via a form (example: subject of teacher with id 5 is changed from 8 to 9), I want to update my timetable table with the new subject assigned.

(**consider the subject field in the teacher-subject table will be updated somehow**).

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you triying to.do. maybe something like a update with join? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join

Comment: @batz : nop, i dont want to join any table.. just replace multiple column values in one update query.

Comment: Somthing like "UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2 where id=1"¿

Comment: use cascading functionality... this will help you more..

Comment: can you please give some demo code, so we understand what you exactly want

Comment: @deemi: when i update the teacher of a subject in the subject-teacher table using "update timetable set tchr=4 where subject=4", the mon_tchr and tue_tchr columns in the teacher-subject table should be changed.. not automatically but what query should be used to do this?

Comment: and what is in mon_tch, tue_tch, are you save teacher id or subject id

Comment: mon contains the subject_id and mon_tch contains teacher_id @deemi

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed: you make a very difficult DB structure, if you understand what "strawberry" says in his answer then you have your solution....if you want solution with "your" db structure ... its a very long but possible solution ..... what you say

Comment: @deemi : i understand that Strawberry's solution by normalizing my table is the smartest way, but i am curious about the update query that updates multiple columns. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62407/discussion-between-deemi-and-arshad-muhammed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normalised design might look like this...

```
period day subject teacher 
--------------------------
 1     mon   4       5       
 1     tue   8       7  
 1     wed   6       3    
 2     mon   6       3       
 2     tue   4       5      
 2     wed   8       7
```

... where (period,day) constitutes a compound PK. That said, there may still be some redundancy here.