# Update a column in a database with values from another colum of another database

Tags: mysql

I need to update a column in a database with values from another column of another database.

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE dbA.tableA as a
SET a.columnA = b.columnB
FROM dbB.tableB as B
WHERE
a.num = b.num
```

And I get the error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ...

Both databases are in the same server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql update join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format of update with join is

```
UPDATE dbA.tableA  a
join dbB.tableB b on a.num = b.num
SET a.columnA = b.columnB
```