# Performing a MySQL UPDATE with multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works...

```
SELECT u.route_id, g.route_id
FROM user_route u
JOIN user_address a ON a.address_id = u.route_begin_id
JOIN user_address b ON b.address_id = u.route_finish_id
JOIN google_route g ON g.route_begin_id = a.address_google_id 
AND g.route_finish_id = b.address_google_id
```

But I would like to update u.google_route_id with g.route_id's value

Can anyone suggest how I go about this, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql update join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Answer (score 0):

```
update user_route u
JOIN user_address a ON a.address_id = u.route_begin_id
JOIN user_address b ON b.address_id = u.route_finish_id
JOIN google_route g ON g.route_begin_id = a.address_google_id 
AND g.route_finish_id = b.address_google_id)
set u.google_route_id=g.route_id
```