# Update 1 MYSQL table with results of SELECT QUERY of another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a mysql table named MEMBER with a date column called 'joined'. Unfortunately the initial code for my application did not update this column properly so the first couple of thousand members have a null joined value.

I have successfully written a query (below) that finds the first date a member made a transaction from table TRANSACTIONSUMMARY and safely assumes this is the date they probably joined.

```
SELECT `member_id`,`member_name`, `created` 
from transactionsummary
group by `member_id`
```

The problem I am having is how to update MEMBER.joined with the TRANSACTIONSUMMARY.created value for every member that has a null joined value. I can manage to update 1 member at a time with a WHERE member.id = "1" for eg but is it possible to do all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You can write update with join, as described there:
[How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

But I am not sure how `group by` will work with that. If not, you will need to put the result from transactionsummary to temporary table and then join memeber with temp table.