# SQL Update using values from other columns in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, laravel

I have an SQL table, "data", with the following columns: 
id (int),
date1 (datetime),
date2 (datetime), 
difference (float)

What I would like to do is update this table so that the "difference" column contains the difference in years (as a float) between date2 and date1, only when date2 doesn't equal '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

I was thinking of something along the lines

```
Update data m
SET difference = datediff("hh",m.date2, m0.date1)/8765 --there are 8765 hours per year so this should give me my float
FROM data m0
WHERE m.id = m0.id
AND m.date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Yet when I try this I get an error stating "SQL syntax error. Check your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near data SET difference = datediff("hh,m.date2,m0.date10/8765) from 'd' at line 1"

How would I modify my sql statement to get the desired results?

EDIT:

I am using xampp's phpMyAdmin interface to run this sql statement

Comment: `Update data SET difference = datediff('hh',date2, date1)/8765 where date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

Comment: update [...] set [...] from is not a valid update statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql update join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Answer (score 0):

[Update](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) statements are suppose to be on the form:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE conditions;
```

Your `from` clause is thus irrelevant.

You can use `joins` and sub `select`-queries though to link to other tables.

-- There are excellent [demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join) on how to achieve that (actually, a complete duplicate):

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to Norbert's advice

I used

```
update data m, data m0
set m.difference = datediff(date(m.date2),date(m0.date2))/365
where m.id = m0.id
and m.date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

I was using the incorrect syntax for mysql datediff, which takes 2 dates as a parameter and returns the difference in days.

Comment: you don't need to join to update the same table, you're wasting resources

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax for update with multiple tables:

```
Update data m, data m0
SET m.difference = datediff("hh",m.date2, m0.date1)/8765 
WHERE m.id = m0.id
AND m.date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Note that in the SET statement you also need to indicate which table you are updating else it will still give you a nice warning.

Comment: Thanks, still some people has actively down voted the answer though.

Comment: You deserve better, Norbert :)