# UPDATE mySQL table using JOIN when two values match

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I'm attempting to use the following code to `JOIN` my MySQL tables, `TableA` and `TableB`, when both their `owner` and `pos` columns match, setting `TableA`'s `val` in the matching record to `TableB`'s `val`:

```
UPDATE TableA A 
JOIN TableB B
ON A.owner = B.owner AND A.pos = B.pos
SET A.val = B.val
```

TableA has around 100,000 records and TableB has around 10,000 and there should only be one `owner`/`pos` match in each table.

When I execute this query everything just hangs and I end up having to abort the execution. Is there something I'm missing syntactically or otherwise to get my desired result?

**Edit:**

I have also tried the following; the results were the same:

```
UPDATE TableA 
JOIN TableB
ON TableA.owner = TableB.owner AND TableA.pos = TableB.pos
SET TableA.val = TableB.val
```

Comment: prepend `EXPLAIN` to the query and see what MySQL has to say. Post results here :)

Comment: With `EXPLAIN` the output is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE TableA A 
JOIN TableB B
ON A.owner = B.owner' at line 2

Comment: Can you select the join?
`SELECT * FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON TableA.owner = TableB.owner AND TableA.pos = TableB.pos`

Comment: Also, can we see the Schema?

Comment: Yes, I am able to select from the above `JOIN`. Both tables have `INT`s for their owner and pos columns and `TINYINT`s for their val column.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
    A.owner = B.owner AND A.pos = B.pos
with 
(A.owner = B.owner AND A.pos = B.pos) and see if Explain plan gives any error?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` gives the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE TableA A 
JOIN TableB B
ON (A.owner = B.owner ' at line 2

Comment: you can refer this link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql
It should resolve your issue.

Comment: I added `INNER JOIN` but that didn't solve it. That was the only difference between my code and that answer's code that I could see.

Answer (score 0):

Below query may help:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.val = B.val
from TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.owner = B.owner AND A.pos = B.pos
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join The `SET` is after the join there.