# Error in running SQL Query in PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Table Schema:

```
Employee (empid, emp_name, age, DOB, designation, doj, basic_salary, salary_amt, medical_allowance, pension, GPFund, TA, House_allowance)
Monthly_salary (id, empid, year, month, total_salary)
```

Query:

```
UPDATE `monthly_salary` 
     SET `total_salary`=`employee`.'salary_amt' -`employee`.'medical_allownces' - `employee`.'pension' 
     WHERE `employee`.'empid'=`monthly_salary`.'emp_id'
```

I'm trying to run this Query in phpmyadmin but its not running and giving errors.
Employees empid is used as foreign key in monthly-salary table.

Comment: Post your table schema

Comment: @Uchiha see updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single qoutes `'`

Should looke like this

```
UPDATE `monthly_salary` salary
JOIN    `employee`      employee    ON employee.empid=salary.emp_id
SET     salary.total_salary=employee.salary_amt - employee.medical_allownces - employee.pension
```

I gave the tables alias names, makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

join in update is not used in your query.

```
UPDATE monthly_salary a
    JOIN employee b  ON  b.empid = a.emp_id
SET a.total_salary=b.salary_amt - b.medical_allownces - b.pension;
```

Comment: following error is occurring: <br \>
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''empid'=`monthly_salary`.'emp_id'
SET `total_salary`=`employee`.'salary_amt' -`' at line 2

Comment: I you facing syntax error, becasue i can't test lack of db. you can use the link-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join

Comment: Remove those quotes from column name

Comment: @hitesh Thanks for helping.<br \>
can u tell me one thing more please  <br \>
in database connection 
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
root location is where ? were should i store my database in xamp folder?

Comment: @KhurramShehzad localhost is host where your mysql server is running. (localhost means your computer have ) root is user name, and "" contain password, which is currently blank.  database is stored in xampp/mysql/data folder