# copy one table data from another

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

table a contains:

```
ID: 1  Name: X 
    2        y
    3        z
```

table B contains:

```
ID:1    name:
   2         
   2
```

May i know how to copy the name from table a to table b and what will happen to
 to table b containing the same id.

Comment: You should show what you tried so far

Comment: You forgot other **RDBMS** tags like `sql server`, `postgresql`, `db2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update table b.

```
Update b1
set b1.name=a1.name
from b b1
join a a1 on a1.id=b1.id
```

If table b is contain same id then same name updated.

Comment: @Madhivanan You can refer this link for mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UPDATE` in following without joining tables:

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET Name = ( SELECT Name 
             FROM table_b b
             WHERE b.id = a.id )
```

Or you can do It by joining tables in following:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Name = b.Name 
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

already id values are present in tableb so you have to use use update statement for copying name column values.

```
update tableb b set name= (select a.name from tablea a
    inner join
    tableb b
    on
    a.id=b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for MysqL

```
Update b as b1 inner join a as a1 on a1.id=b1.id
set b1.name=a1.name
```