# Update order value in table - mysql select query has multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty good with mySQL but for some reason I'm struggling to get my head around this one.

I need to programmatically update the order values in the wp_esp_ticket table as the dates get out of order sometimes. This is the query I have to use to bring back all the dates that are related to each other and need ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_esp_ticket` et 
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime_ticket edtt on edtt.TKT_ID = et.TKT_ID
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime edt on edtt.DTT_ID = edt.DTT_ID
WHERE edt.EVT_ID = 1325
```

This brings back all the rows that need updating in the correct order, but the TKT_order column in the wp_esp_ticket table is then out of sequence. I need to give the top row a value of 1 in the column TKT_order and go up in increments of 1 for each row below.

I need to put together a tidy sql statement for this as it will need to be run along with another peice of code that adds new dates to the database.

Thanksss!!!

**Update:**

Thanks to the input and direction from Drew I got this to work:

```
SET @newnum = 0;

Update wp_esp_ticket tix

INNER JOIN (
SELECT TKT_ID FROM `wp_esp_ticket` et 
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime_ticket edtt on edtt.TKT_ID = et.TKT_ID
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime edt on edtt.DTT_ID = edt.DTT_ID
WHERE edt.EVT_ID = 1325
ORDER BY edt.DTT_EVT_start ASC
) b ON tix.TKT_ID = b.TKT_ID

SET tix.TKT_order = @newnum:=@newnum + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) near the top of the page.

> For example, if the table contains 1 and 2 in the id column and 1 is
>   updated to 2 before 2 is updated to 3, an error occurs. To avoid this
>   problem, add an ORDER BY clause to cause the rows with larger id
>   values to be updated before those with smaller values:
>
> UPDATE t SET id = id + 1 ORDER BY id DESC;

Note that is a conceptual from the manual. Tweak accordingly.

Combine the update / order by with the concept of `update with a join` ([How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)) and you are all set.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

In your case, I diverge, going with a rownum:

```
set @rownum:=0;

update `wp_esp_ticket` et 
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime_ticket edtt on edtt.TKT_ID = et.TKT_ID
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime edt on edtt.DTT_ID = edt.DTT_ID
set TKT_order =@rownum:=@rownum+1
WHERE edt.EVT_ID = 1325
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
see this rough example in action:

create table j
(   k varchar(20) not null,
    theOrder int not null
);

insert j(k,theOrder) values ('z',-1),('gj',-1),('w',-1),('h',-1),('uw',-1),('b',-1);

set @rownum:=0;
update j
set theOrder=@rownum:=@rownum+1
order by k;

+----+----------+
| k  | theOrder |
+----+----------+
| b  |        1 |
| gj |        2 |
| h  |        3 |
| uw |        4 |
| w  |        5 |
| z  |        6 |
+----+----------+
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Thanks Drew, any chance of a quick example of how I'd nest my select query in the update?

Comment: Thanks Drew, did a little shuffling around and posted the solution above! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `TKT_order` is a existing column or a calculated column. If it's an existing column then what if you add a `order by` clause on `TKT_order`

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_esp_ticket` et 
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime_ticket edtt on edtt.TKT_ID = et.TKT_ID
INNER JOIN wp_esp_datetime edt on edtt.DTT_ID = edt.DTT_ID
WHERE edt.EVT_ID = 1325
ORDER BY et.TKT_order; <-- This one
```

Comment: TKT_order all ready exists but the numbers are wrong/out of sequence. I need to repopulate that column based on the date column asc...