# How to avoid full table scan when update with IN clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, in-clause, full-table-scan

I got 2 MySQL tables: termlist and blacklist. They both have index on field 'term' and blacklist has another index on field 'status'.

I want to update status of  terms  in termlist, that also appear in blacklist with status as 'A', to 'B', I issue this SQL statement:

```
update termlist set status = 'B' where term in (select term from blacklist where status = 'A')
```

It cause a full table scan on termlist. I want to use 'update with inner join' but I can't since there's a where clause in select statement.

I know I can create a temp table from that select statement and then update inner join with that temp table but this is kinda tedious if I want to do this update many times.

Is there one single update statement that can do the work without full table scan?

Comment: table schemas showing index info not hand typed please, `show create table xxx` for each

Comment: if that is even necessary ... so skip what I just said ... You want to use the update with table join pattern see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
update termlist t inner join blacklist b 
    on t.term=b.term
    set t.status = 'B' 
    where b.status = 'A'
```

Comment: I will use 2 temp tables to try your statement. If they come out right answer, I'll check your answer.