# Set Meta Value #1 for Meta Key #1 Only When Meta Value #2 and Meta Key #2 is Present

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to make updates to my WordPress DataBase but I keep hitting a roadblock when taking into consideration a secondary condition.

In very simplistic terms, I have a **meta_key = 'flowers'** that needs a **meta_value = 'roses'** to be set only where **meta_key = 'month'** and **meta_value = 'august'**.

I have not been able to write a successful MySQL query that includes the second condition. I know how to do this:

```php
update wp_postmeta
  set meta_value = 'roses'
where meta_key = 'flowers'
```

but it is not limited to only **meta_key = 'month'** and **meta_value = 'august'**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE #1:

As requested by @Strawberry, to give further detail to my question.  I am not entirely sure how but the meta_key = 'flowers' and the meta_key = 'month' must be related.  As it stands, all posts consist of a meta_key = 'flowers' and the meta_key = 'month'.

UPDATE #2:

I was able to receive help from @Rahul, here is the version that worked for me:

```php
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND 
                      b.meta_key = 'month' AND 
                      b.meta_value = 'august'
  SET    a.meta_value = 'roses'
WHERE  a.meta_key = 'flowers';
```

Hopefully, it will help others as well.  Also, for further detail on JOIN, see:  [How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join)

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The `exists` operator should do the job:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
SET    a.meta_value = 'roses'
WHERE  a.meta_key = 'flowers' AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   wp_postmeta b
               WHERE  a.post_id = b.post_id AND 
                      b.meta_key = 'month' AND 
                      b.meta_value = 'august')
```

Comment: @Strawberry Hmm... good point :-) Edited my answer, that was dumb on my behalf.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to answer your question.  Are you referring to meta_key = flowers and meta_key = month being related?  Is this where a post_id is required?

Comment: @Jorge Well, yes - how else can we know that they are related - but this is too important a point to discuss in comments. Perhaps you could amend your question.

Comment: I executed the query and received the following error:  #1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause