# MYSQL select, join, sum and update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, select

I am retrieving data from my db with this query:

```
SELECT
  users.id as id,
  users.username as UserName,
  users.wochenh as wochenh,
  ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) as monatsstunden,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) AS total,
  users.uberh as OLD_VALUE,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) - ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) AS ueberh,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) - ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) + users.uberh AS NEW_VALUE
  FROM time_entries
  inner join users on users.id = time_entries.user_id
  WHERE start BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
  GROUP BY user_id
```

This gives me my information fine like this:

```
    id    UserName  wochenh monatsstunden   total   OLD_VALUE   ueberh  NEW_VALUE
#1  "3"    "ph"      "32"      "137"        "168"   "200"       "31"    "231"
#2  "4"    "me"      "28"      "120"        "173"   "164"       "53"    "217"
#3  "6"    "dp"      "24"      "103"        "89"    "-10"       "-14"   "-24"
#4  "12"   "ab"      "10"      "43"         "26"    "24"        "-17"   "7"
#5  "13"   "fh"      "9"       "39"         "44"    "25"        "5"     "30"
```

Now my question is: How can I set OLD_VALUE to NEW_VALUE in this query?

Please help! Best,
Chris

Comment: You are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query

Comment: Thanks! That helped very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN (SELECT
  users.id as id,
  users.username as UserName,
  users.wochenh as wochenh,
  ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) as monatsstunden,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) AS total,
  users.uberh as OLD_VALUE,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) - ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) AS ueberh,
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end))/60,0) - ROUND(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH))/7*users.wochenh,0) + users.uberh AS NEW_VALUE
  FROM time_entries
  inner join users on users.id = time_entries.user_id
  WHERE start BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
  GROUP BY user_id) e ON u.id = e.id
  SET u.uberh = e.NEW_VALUE
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to make sure this question already has the correct answer.