# Finding matching pairs between two tables and returning a third value to be inserted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, string-matching, multiple-tables

I'm working in a database with MySQL thought phpMyAdmin, and it's important to know that my knowledge on MySQL is pretty limited.

I have two tables in my database. I need to take the `img_id` column values in the second table (wp_posts_thumbs), find the matching pair in the first table (wp_posts), take the corresponding value in the `ID` column in the first table, and insert it in the `post_parent` column in the second table.

This is what the first table (wp_posts) looks like:

```
+------+-------------------------+
| ID   | img_id                  |
+------+-------------------------+
| 1    | W048zewxemq1tw0810aiec  |
| 2    | W0481l2lv4npdczok5mmucl |
| 3    | W0481j9w7fg80b8gkiida85 |
+------+-------------------------+
```

This is what the second table (wp_posts_thumbs) looks like:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| ID   | img_id                  | post_parent |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
| 101  | W048zewxemq1tw0810aiec  | 0           |
| 102  | W0481l2lv4npdczok5mmucl | 0           |
| 103  | W0481j9w7fg80b8gkiida85 | 0           |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: shouldn't you post your third table (post_parent) as well?

Comment: There's no third table, mate :/ `post_parent` is a third column located in the `wp_posts_thumbs` table, just like I illustrated it in my message's content.

Comment: Sorry misread your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `Id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `img_id` VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts_thumbs` (
  `Id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `img_id` VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` INT(11)
);

INSERT INTO wp_posts (id,img_id) VALUES (1,'aiec');
INSERT INTO wp_posts (id,img_id) VALUES (2,'mucl');
INSERT INTO wp_posts (id,img_id) VALUES (3,'da85');
INSERT INTO wp_posts_thumbs (id,img_id,post_parent) VALUES (101,'aiec',0);
INSERT INTO wp_posts_thumbs (id,img_id,post_parent) VALUES (102,'mucl',0);
INSERT INTO wp_posts_thumbs (id,img_id,post_parent) VALUES (103,'da85',0);

UPDATE wp_posts_thumbs 
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts 
        ON wp_posts_thumbs.img_id = wp_posts.img_id 
    SET post_parent = wp_posts.id 
    WHERE wp_posts_thumbs.img_id = wp_posts.img_id;
```

Yields the following:

```
101 aiec    1
102 mucl    2
103 da85    3
```

Comment: I'm trying to test your suggestion, but I'm getting the following error message: `#1052 - Column 'post_parent' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: That's weird, I did not get such a message.  Anyhow, try `wp_posts_thumbs.post_parent`.

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that on my own right after I posted my previous comment :P But I've been waiting for 9 hours already and MySQL hasn't finished processing that query. I might need to add new indexes or something. It's taking too long I don't know how to fix it. I only have 4500 rows, it shouldn't be taking that long.

Comment: That's also very weird.  With 4500 rows it should be done fairly quickly, even if you have not specified any indexes.  But yes, try adding indexes for `img_id` on both tables, and also make sure that `post_parent` is *not* indexed while updating it. (If it needs to be indexed, then drop the index prior to updating, and add it again once updating is complete.)

Comment: OMG! Now it worked perfectly and in less than a minute! The breaking point was at indexing `img_id` column. That little thing speeded up the whole process. I wouldn't have never guessed how important indexes are. Thank you, thank you so much for your help, @Mike Nakis! I've learn a big lesson thanks to you (and solved a little problem too :P).

Answer (score 0):

This is requires UPDATE with JOIN. You may want to refer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86e71/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts
    (`ID` int, `img_id` varchar(23))
;

INSERT INTO wp_posts
    (`ID`, `img_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 'W048zewxemq1tw0810aiec'),
    (2, 'W0481l2lv4npdczok5mmucl'),
    (3, 'W0481j9w7fg80b8gkiida85')
;


CREATE TABLE wp_posts_thumbs
    (`ID` int, `img_id` varchar(23), `post_parent` int)
;

INSERT INTO wp_posts_thumbs
    (`ID`, `img_id`, `post_parent`)
VALUES
    (101, 'W048zewxemq1tw0810aiec', 0),
    (102, 'W0481l2lv4npdczok5mmucl', 0),
    (103, 'W0481j9w7fg80b8gkiida85', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
UPDATE wp_posts_thumbs  wpt
   JOIN wp_posts wp ON wpt.img_id = wp.img_id  
   SET wpt.post_parent = wp.id
;

SELECT * FROM wp_posts_thumbs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86e71/1/0)**:

```
|  ID |                  img_id | post_parent |
|-----|-------------------------|-------------|
| 101 |  W048zewxemq1tw0810aiec |           1 |
| 102 | W0481l2lv4npdczok5mmucl |           2 |
| 103 | W0481j9w7fg80b8gkiida85 |           3 |
```