# How do I assign this concatenated value back to its table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having beginner troubles with MySQL. I'm trying to build a DB of parts which have a ten digit alphanumeric part number based on the department and class of a part. For example, a part from department "Foo" of class "Bar" might be *FOBAR10000*. The departments and classes are stored in their own tables, so I store the IDs with the part instead of the strings "FO" and "BAR" in the parts table.

I've come up with a MySQL query to lookup and concatenate the full part name.

```
SELECT pl.idPartsList as 'resultid', concat(pd.DeptShortName, pc.ClassShortName,pl.PartIntID) as 'Fullname'
FROM partdepartments pd, partclasses pc, partslist pl
WHERE pl.PartDeptId = pd.idPartDepartments and pl.PartClassID = pc.idPartClasses;
```

Which generates:

```
resultid | Fullname
---------------------
1        | FOBAR10000
```

I want to assign this result back to the part under the column PartFullAlphaID, as follows, to avoid having to run this query often.

Before:

```
idPartslist | PartDeptID | PartClassID | PartIntID | PartFullAlphaID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1          | 1           | 10000     |
```

After:

```
idPartslist | PartDeptID | PartClassID | PartIntID | PartFullAlphaID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1          | 1           | 10000     | FOBAR10000
```

but the following doesn't work:

```
UPDATE test_db_1.partslist 
SET PartFullAlphaID = Fullname 
WHERE test_db_1.partslist.idPartsList = resultid;
```

Because: *Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'resultid' in 'where clause'*

How can I assign this string value back to the part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an update on joined tables.
Try this Query:

```
UPDATE partslist pl
    JOIN partdepartments pd ON pl.PartDeptId = pd.idPartDepartments
    JOIN partclasses pc ON pl.PartClassID = pc.idPartClasses
SET pl.PartFullAlphaID = concat(pd.DeptShortName, pc.ClassShortName, pl.PartIntID)
```

also look at [stackoverflow.com/../how-to-use-join-in-update-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the results out into variables?

```
DECLARE @ResultID varchar(10),
        @FullName varchar(100)


SELECT  @ResultID = pl.idPartsList, 
        @FullName = concat(pd.DeptShortName, pc.ClassShortName,pl.PartIntID)
FROM    partdepartments pd, partclasses pc, partslist pl
WHERE   pl.PartDeptId = pd.idPartDepartments 
    AND pl.PartClassID = pc.idPartClasses;


UPDATE  test_db_1.partslist 
SET     PartFullAlphaID = @FullName 
WHERE   test_db_1.partslist.idPartsList = @ResultID;
```

I use `MSSQL` so the syntax may be (very slightly) different, but I use this syntax often when updating records.

Answer (score 0):

You can just a subquery that generates the concatenated value on the fly:

```
UPDATE test_db_1.partslist 
SET PartFullAlphaID = (
    SELECT concat(pd.DeptShortName, pc.ClassShortName, partslist.PartIntID)
    FROM partdepartments pd, partclasses pc
    WHERE partslist.PartDeptId = pd.idPartDepartments 
    and partslist.PartClassID = pc.idPartClasses
)
--add a filter if you only want to update a subset of the partslist table
--WHERE partslist.<criteria> = <whatever>
```

Good luck!