# Mysql double data on query

Tags: mysql

I have data on 2 tables, like this

```
Table 1
no|   name  |  address |
1 | alex    |  br st   | 
2 | ujang   |  cilala  |
3 | adu     |  lind st |
4 | ujang   |  bilila  |
5 | ujang   |  gea     |

Table 2
no|   name  |  address |
1 | alex    |          |
2 | ujang   |          |
3 | adu     |          |
4 | adu     |          |
```

My Query is like this

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a 
JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.name = b.name
SET a.address = b.address
```

Result that i want

```
 Table 2
    no|   name  |  address |
    1 | alex    |  br st   |
    2 | ujang   |  cilala  |
    3 | adu     |  lind st |
    4 | adu     |  lind st |
```

That all i don't have word to say, i'am freeze.

Comment: With regard to duplicates, how do you want to deal with the possibility that there may be more than one matching name in the first table?  If you can articulate this to us, we can give you an answer.

Comment: Do you want to update the address of second table if name match in first table?

Comment: Maybe you want to check http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/ for a start.

Comment: yes i want to update address with table 1,

Comment: @SAE If I understand you correctly, you are trying to copy the address from Table 1 to Table2 if the names match?

Comment: What is the logic behind choosing `cilala` as the address for `ujang`?  This isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @marklong yes is that but i have many address and i want only one, from the top.

Comment: @tim my logic is for choosing the very first value from table1 because some of the data have bad address at the second record. but it have field that important, so i can't erase it.

Comment: This is clear, you want the record with the smallest `id` value.

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query

Comment: @tim  yes that maybe the best answer that i want for now.

Comment: for vinod and vishal,  thanks. But i'am already see the question and don't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query updates `TABLE2` using a temporary table containing only records from `TABLE1` with the minimum `no` value, in cases where a `name` may occur more than once in `TABLE1`.

```
UPDATE TABLE2 a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.no, t1.name, t1.address
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT name, MIN(no) AS no
        FROM TABLE1
        GROUP BY name
    ) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.no = t2.no
) b ON a.name = b.name
SET a.address = b.address
```

Comment: i have answer from MySQL "Location name in field list is ambiguous", i still try it.

Comment: @SAE Sorry, I was missing a table alias.  Please try it again.

Comment: it have some error but, yes thank you @tim, its works now

Answer (score 0):

As you mention i think you want all the addresses in table2 from tabel1,so if you want that please change the query with this one :

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.name = b.name SET b.address = a.address
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
UPDATE table2 
SET 
table2.address = table1.address

FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.name = table2.name
```