# Change value in child table if parent table record meets condition

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have a table

```
parent_table {ID,code}
```

2 colums. `ID` - primary key

```
childe_table {ID,parent_table_ID, Name}
```

3 columns. `parent_table_id` is foreign key

I'm trying to create query to do this:

```
if(parent_table.code == 'x'){
    child_table.Name == 'value'
}
```

I know that I should use joins to do this.
Could someone show me an example?

Comment: i don't understand your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209489/4843530).  You need to do

```
 UPDATE childe_table ct 
   JOIN parent_table pt ON ct.parent_table_id = pt.id  
   SET ct.code="value"
   WHERE pt.code='x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update childe_table c 
set c.Name="value" 
where (select p.code from parent_table p where p.id=c.parent_table_id)="x"
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way of doing an update across a join.  Instead of doing the join in the update, you are doing it on an inner select statement that gets executed for every record in the child table.