# MYSQL Joining two tables with one identical column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: table 1 = university and table 2 = school

I added `university_id` into the table 2 and I need to connect the two tables.

If `university_name` from table 1 and `name` from table 2 are identical, get the `id` from table 1 and replace it onto table 2 `university_id`

I am very new to sql so if you could explain that would be great. I have also tried the following with no avail!

```
     select a.id,b.name from university as a
     inner join school as b on a.university_name = b.name
     UPDATE `school` SET `university_id` = a.id WHERE a.university_name = b.name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JOIN in UPDATE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query)

Comment: This is smelling a lot like Friday homework to me (since the duplicate above is exactly the same)

Comment: its not friday homework! I swear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE school a 
JOIN university b ON a.university_name = b.name
SET a.university_id = b.id
```

should work

Comment: It does work thank you so much that looks way more simpler then what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot run a test right now... Maybe it does give you a hint.

```
UPDATE `school` s SET `university_id` = (SELECT u.id FROM `university` u WHERE u.name=s.university_name)
```

You might need to JOIN the school-table within the SELECT statement.

Comment: I have also tried this and it also worked thank you!