# Update table value for records based on join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a table named product. In this table, I want to update some product id values, however I cannot do it directly, my 'where' condition needs to determine records based on value from another table, so I do:

```
update product set prod_active = 0 where prod_id in (
select prod_id from user_prod_sel where seltype = 100
)
```

The problem I have here is this is very slow. How can I convert this into a oin based query that can give me faster results?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
UPDATE product a 
JOIN user_prod_sel b ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id AND b.selType = 100 
SET a.prod_active = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up the query you need to add indexes for `product.prod_id` and `user_prod_sel.seltype`. Table indexes exist exactly for speeding up selection of data.

```
ALTER TABLE `product` ADD INDEX `prod_id` (`prod_id`)
```

Do not add index `product.prod_id` if it already has index (if it's a primary key, for example).

```
ALTER TABLE `user_prod_sel` ADD INDEX `seltype` (`seltype`)
```

And then:

```
UPDATE `product`, `user_prod_sel`
SET `product`.`prod_active` = 0
WHERE 
    `product`.`prod_id` = `user_prod_sel`.`prod_id` AND
    `user_prod_sel`.`seltype` = 100
```

Of course, creating indexes is a task which is performed once, not before every `UPDATE` query.