# How to migrate SQL update query to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table called 'Books' with the following structure and records:

```
+--------+----------------------------+----------+
| BookID |          BookName          | Language |
+--------+----------------------------+----------+
|      1 | Le Comte de Monte-Cristo   | FR       |
|      1 | The Count of Monte Cristo  | EN       |
|      2 | Les Trois Mousquetaires    | FR       |
|      2 | The Three Musketeers       | EN       |
+--------+----------------------------+----------+
```

I want to overwrite the FR book name from EN based on the ID.

I have a SQL Server query that works, but when I try to run it on a PHPMyAdmin (MySQL) database, I receive an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

The MS SQL Server query:

```
UPDATE
    a
SET
    BookName = B.BookName
FROM
    Books a
    CROSS JOIN Books b
WHERE
    a.Language = 'FR' AND
    b.Language = 'EN' AND
    a.BookID   = b.BookID
```

Can someone, please, tell me where the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error message? MySQL should be telling you more information about the error, such as the line number or the exact syntax error description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JOIN in UPDATE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it, but I'm guessing the statement you want is:

```
UPDATE Books A 
JOIN Books B ON A.BookID = B.BookID
SET A.BookName = B.BookName 
WHERE A.Language='FR' AND B.Language='EN'
```

A `cross join` makes a cartesian product, and in your example where you have a `where` clause that references each table, it turns in to an `inner join`

Comment: I think `WHERE` clause should be present after `SET`

Comment: @Prdp Fixed. Thanks for noticing.