# Subquery returns more than 1 row while update

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing one simple SQL query to update my table .

here  is my code

```
$qry = mysql_query("update product set cat_tree =(select cat_name from cat_details where product.category = cat_details.cat_id )");
```

When ever i tried to run this code its giving error message

> #1242 - Sub query returns more than 1 row

What is the problem ? I tried with so many solutions like "IN" "ANY" . But all examples are for insert query only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That query returns multiple rows, you need to make it return 1 row. So there is only 1 value for it to set.

Comment: probably "cat_details.cat_id" is not unique

Comment: add "limit 1" at the end of the query

Comment: It will make the query return only 1 row. It could be the incorrect result though. You will need to give it an appropriate `order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try LIMIT like this...

```
$qry = mysql_query("update product set cat_tree =(select cat_name from cat_details where product.category = cat_details.cat_id LIMIT 1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update product p join cat_details c on p.category = c.cat_id
set p.cat_tree = c.cat_name
where p.category =  c.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an UPDATE query with a JOIN ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query)):

```
UPDATE product AS p 
  JOIN cat_details AS c
  ON p.category = c.cat_id 
SET p.cat_tree = c.cat_name;
```