# Synchronising a table's key field from one database to another

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 databases

```
Test1

Test2
```

and I have `Author` table in each database, I would like to sync  `AuthorId` from `Test1` to `Test2`.

In `Test2` also there is another table `ProductAuthor` which has the f`oreign Key constraint on AuthorID in Author table`.

What I am doing at the moment is

1. Drop the foreign key constraint
2. Update the both tables : Author and ProductAuthor
3. Add the foreign key constraint

   ```
    --remove the foreign key constraint

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductAuthor] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductAuthor_Author]

   Update Test2.dbo.ProductAuthor set AuthorId = (
   select distinct T1A.AuthorId from Test1.dbo.Author T1A 
   INNER JOIN Test2.dbo.Author T2A ON T1A.FirstName =  T2A.firstname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS and T1A.LastName =  T2A.surname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
   where T2A.AuthorId = ProductAuthor.AuthorId
   ) where ProductAuthor.AuthorId = 6793

   Update Test2.dbo.Author set AuthorId = (
   select Distinct T1A.AuthorId from Test1.dbo.Author T1A 
   INNER JOIN Test2.dbo.Author T2A ON T1A.FirstName =  T2A.firstname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS and T1A.LastName =  T2A.surname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
   where T1A.AuthorId = 106793) where Test2.dbo.AuthorId = 6793


   --add the foreign key constraint
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductAuthor]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductAuthor_Author] FOREIGN KEY([AuthorId])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[Author] ([AuthorId])
   ```

The above script updates a `specific AuthorId from Test1.Author to Test2.Author and Test2.ProductAuthor`

**ASK:**
How would I change the script so that it updates all the rows in Test2.Author and Test2.ProductAuthor based on the First Name and last Name in Test1.Author?

Comment: Question is stil unclear,you may need to improve your question ,please look here:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is an update and select as found here:

[How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query)

You'll possibly need to just do a basic join - i.e.

```
JOIN (SELECT * FROM db1.author WHERE ....) as db1
SET db2.author = db1.ID
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Good question - not too sure. Don't use it I'm afraid. But this was flagged for mysql which it should.