# Moving data from one table row to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, first one A, is full of information.  Second one B, is empty.  I want to take a row from table A and put it into table B.  So far I have to start a row(filling in two of the columns) in table B, then update.  Is there way to just create a new row with the other tables info for the row I want, same schema.  I was looking at LEFT JOIN, but couldn't break down how to add it by row.  Below is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE tableB
SET tableB.aaa = (SELECT aaa FROM tableA where id = '1'),
    tableB.bbb = (SELECT bbb FROM tableA where id = '1'),
    tableB.ccc = (SELECT ccc FROM tableA where id = '1'),
    tableB.ddd = (SELECT ddd FROM tableA where id = '1'),
    tableB.eee = (SELECT eee FROM tableA where id = '1'),
where proprietaryname='drugC';
```

Also, is there a way to not make this repetitive. New to SQL, appreciate the help.

Comment: `tableB` is empty right? Then how can you select data from it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Comment: My mistake update question, had table switched in code, same logic applies

Comment: Do they have the same columns and data structures?

Comment: Why am I expecting an `insert` and not an `update`?

Comment: Yes, same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert new rows in tableB from tableA, then you can use `insert . .  select`:

```
insert into tableB(aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee)
    select aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee
    from tableA
    where proprietaryname = 'drugC';
```