# How can I make the sum of two columns of two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I make the sum of two columns of two different tables ?

In my case , I want sum the two columns of different table , and in the first table to return the value added .

Example :

Tbl_one

```
colum ID | colum Point
1        | 1000
2        | 2000
```

tbl_two

```
colum ID | colum Point
1        | 10000
2        | 5000
```

RESULT

Tbl_one

```
colum ID | colum Point
1        | 11000 
2        | 7000
```

I tried this query , but it did not work very well

```
UPDATE tbl_1 SET tlb_1.columX= tbl_1.columX + tbl_2.columY
```

RESULT ERROR: #1054 - Unknown column 'tbl_2.columY' in 'field list'

Comment: why are these two different tables anyway?

Comment: Duplicate perhaps -- you need to use `join` in your `update` statement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15209489/1073631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, one would use a `select` query for this:

```
select id, sum(point)
from ((select id, point from tbl_one) union all
      (select id, point from tbl_two)
     ) t
group by id;
```

If you actually want to update the table, one method uses `join`:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 t1 JOIN
       tbl_2 t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id
    SET t1.Point = t1.Point + t2.Point;
```

However, updating the table seems extreme, if all you want to do is get the aggregated results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a join with `tbl_two` in your update request, which would like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 INNER JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_2.ID = tbl_1.ID SET tbl_1.columX= tbl_1.columX + tbl_2.columY
```