# MYSQL Update Query syntax error 28-10-2016a

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE DFEntryValues
SET DFEntryValues.DFFieldvalue = NOW()
FROM DFEntryValues 
JOIN DFEntries ON DFEntryValues.DFEntryID = DFEntries.DFEntryID
JOIN DynamicFormStructures ON DFEntries.DynamicFormStructureID = DynamicFormStructures.DynamicFormStructureID
JOIN Projects ON DynamicFormStructures.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectId
JOIN Clients ON Projects.ClientID = Clients.ClientID
JOIN DFFieldDefinition ON DFEntryValues.DFFieldDefinitionID = DFFieldDefinition.DFFieldDefinitionID
WHERE Clients.ClientID = '26' AND DFFieldDefinition.label = 'Geboortedatum';
```

I get the following error:

Error Code: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE Clients.ClientID = '26' AND DFFieldDefinition.label = 'Geboortedatum' SET' at line 12

Can someone point me out what's wrong with this query?

Kind regards!!

Comment: I do not see any sense in your query by the way.

Comment: The most important part is missing from the error message: the place where your syntax goes wrong (after the `near` keyword).

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Clients.ClientID = '26' AND DFFieldDefinition.label = 'Geboortedatum'
SET' at line 12

Comment: I want to update a specific field in this table, but can only reach this via all those nested tables.. But correct me if I'm wrong! :-)

Comment: I think the `FROM` keyword is the problem. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15209489/1531853) answer to find the exact format of an update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not using correct format.
Hope this helps.

```
UPDATE DFEntryValues JOIN DFEntries ON DFEntryValues.DFEntryID = DFEntries.DFEntryID
JOIN DynamicFormStructures ON DFEntries.DynamicFormStructureID = DynamicFormStructures.DynamicFormStructureID 
JOIN Projects ON DynamicFormStructures.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectId 
JOIN Clients ON Projects.ClientID = Clients.ClientID 
JOIN DFFieldDefinition ON DFEntryValues.DFFieldDefinitionID = DFFieldDefinition.DFFieldDefinitionID 
SET DFEntryValues.DFFieldvalue = NOW() 
WHERE Clients.ClientID = '26' AND DFFieldDefinition.label = 'Geboortedatum';
```