# I have got this code it is working fine but I want to change the having code into another structure

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is the code I have at the moment which works fine:

```
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM te_events order by eventTitle ASC ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $venueID = $row['venueID'];
        $catID = $row['catID'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM te_venue where venueID='$venueID'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $venueName = $row2['venueName'];
        }

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM te_category where catID='$catID'";
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $catName = $row3['catDesc'];
        }

?>
```

But I want to Change it into this format. I could do only till this bit couldn't go further than this I get errors.

```
<?php
    $sql ="SELECT eventTitle, eventID, venueID, catID, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventPrice FROM te_events ORDER BY eventTitle ASC";
    $queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult)) {

        $venueID = $row['venueID'];
        $catID = $row['catID'];
        $venueName = $row['venueName'];
        $catName = $row['catDesc'];

?>
```

How can I do that then?
how can I join two tables?

Comment: How can i do that then ?

Comment: how can i join two tables ?

Comment: Questions without code won't make sense to future visitors. Please keep the code in the question. If there is some secure data (I'm not seeing any) you should reset it on your server because it has already been exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) the additional 2 tables to get the columns you need.

```
SELECT e.eventTitle, e.eventID, e.venueID, e.catID, e.eventStartDate, e.eventEndDate, e.eventPrice, v.venueName, c.catDesc
 FROM te_events as e
join te_venue as v
on e.venueID = v.venueID
join te_category as c
on c.catID = e.catID
ORDER BY eventTitle ASC
```

You also should avoid putting data directly into a query. If you need to do that use parameterized queries. This is how SQL injections (or second level) occur.

Comment: What did happened? Might need to give `eventTitle` its aliases in the `order by` as well, is that a unique name?

Comment: Oh, I used the wrong aliases. Do you know what this code is doing? You should really understand something before you just go plugging it in. The `e`, `v`, and `c` are aliases for your tables.

Comment: i still dont get it sorry :(

Comment: I've updated the answer, take a look. The `te_events as e` makes all `e.` reference the `te_events` table. If those columns are not in that table correct them, the same with the other `c.` and `v.`.

Comment: Amazing I just copied and pasted that code everything came up right just one more thing how can i avoid SQL injection for this.

Comment: With this approach there is no injection possible. With your previous approach though if `$venueID` or `$catID` contained malicious code you would have been executing it. For future prevention use parameterized queries. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for more information. Please accept this answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: I want to add "location" as well which is in te_venue table how can i add that as well in this sql statement

Comment: Location is already in one of these tables? Use whichever aliases it is and add it to the list of columns the `select` should pull.

Comment: Okay, so see the second part of that comment.

Comment: sorry didn't work here is a screenshot of my tables this might help https://postimg.org/image/6ui8nsi55/

Comment: Whats the SQL you tried? What happened when you ran it, error?

Comment: as v on e.venueID = v.location join te_venue

Comment: The table is already joined. Just add the column to the list of columns you want returned.

Comment: just e.venueID = v.location?

Comment: Just add `v.location` to the list of columns.

Comment: Now for updating I got this  SQL statement "UPDATE te_events SET eventTitle='$title',eventStartDate='$startdate',eventEndDate='$enddate',eventPrice='$price',eventDescription='$description' WHERE eventID=$eventID"; How can i add location in this ?

Comment: These are all separate questions then what you initially asked. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Comment: sorry that page was not helpful

Comment: You need to apply it to your code, it should be the same concept. Ask another question if you are having issues. Include the code and the error(s) (if any).

Comment: hey chris this is the link for my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639779/how-to-add-to-this-update-sql-statement-and-make-a-drop-down-list-too-for-it