# How to add to this update SQL statement and make a drop down list too for it

Tags: php, html

Okay i have this SQL statement for update which works find but I want to add `locations` which is in `te_venue` table after adding the location into sql i want for locations to be a drop down list which user can pick one location from list and when clicked on update it should update.

This is the php code that I have already (I need to add `location` into this)

```
<?php
$eventID = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = "UPDATE te_events SET eventTitle='$title',eventStartDate='$startdate',eventEndDate='$enddate',eventPrice='$price',eventDescription='$description' WHERE eventID=$eventID";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
        header('Location:edit.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error updating record";
    }
}    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM te_events where eventID='$eventID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $eventTitle = $row['eventTitle'];
    $eventDescription = $row['eventDescription'];
    $eventStartDate = $row['eventStartDate'];
    $eventEndDate = $row['eventEndDate'];
    $eventPrice = $row['eventPrice'];      
}
?>
```

And this is where i want to have a drop down list for location.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="title">Title</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="title" required/ value="<?php echo $eventTitle; ?>"><br/>
    <label for="startdate">Start Date</label><br/>
    <input type="date" name="startdate" required/ value="<?php echo $eventStartDate; ?>"><br/>
    <label for="enddate">End Date</label><br/>
    <input type="date" name="enddate" required/ value="<?php echo $eventEndDate; ?>"><br/>
    <label for="price">Price (£)</label><br/>
    <input type="number" step="any" name="price" required/ value="<?php echo $eventPrice; ?>"><br/>
    <label for="description">Description</label><br/>
    <textarea name="description" cols="55" rows="5"><?php echo $eventDescription; ?></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="button">
</form>
```

Here is a screenshot of my tables too it might help.

https://postimg.org/image/6ui8nsi55/

Comment: Each venue has only one location. So why would you have a dropdown menu listing all the locations?

Comment: maybe if somone wants to change the venue location from one place to another.

Comment: By "someone" do you mean a user or an admin?

Comment: Admin only ....

Comment: OK. And do you want the list of places pulled from the database or just hardcoded into the dropdown?

Comment: just hardcoded into the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?  Getting the location from te_venue and adding the results to a select?

```
<select>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT location FROM te_venue";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        }
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['location'];?>"><?php echo $row['location'];?> </option>

    <?php
        }
      ?>
</select>
```

Comment: No sorry I want the location in update SQL that i got already then in drop down list i want to list few locations my self not from locations that i got already in my table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="location">Choose a location: </label>
<select class="form-control" name="location">
  <option value="London">London</option>
  <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
  <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
  <option value="Moscow">Moscow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your post action is blank:
`<form method="post" action="">`
You need to tell the form which code is going to run after the button is pressed.