# MySQL query not working, syntax error near INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

Not done any programming for a few years so am somewhat rusty again.

I have two tables `users` table and `users_profiles` table. I want to update `users_profiles` table on the condition that `user_uid` matches on both tables (`users.user_uid` and `users_profiles.user_uid`) and where `users.user_login = 'johndoe'` and `users.user_uid = '11'`.

It will be executed in a php script, so johndoe would actually be users username (whatever is stored in session and same for users_uid. For simplicitity i added dummy data.

I run the query in phpmyadmin and get syntax error near INNER JOIN. I just cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong (probably wrote it entirely wrong) and have spent few hours trying to work it out without success.

Heres my sql query.

```
    UPDATE 
      users_profiles
    SET 
      users_profiles.user_fname = 'John', 
      users_profiles.user_lname = 'Doe', 
      users_profiles.user_gender = 'male'
    INNER JOIN 
      users
    ON
      users.user_uid = users_profiles.user_uid
    WHERE
      users.user_login = 'johndoe'
    AND
      users.user_uid = '11'
```

error i get when running sql query via phpmyadmin.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use  
near 'ON users.user_uid, .user_uid FROM users_profiles WHERE   
users.user_login ' at line 7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to exchange `SET` and `INNER JOIN` as shown, for example, in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209489/2630032):

```
UPDATE 
      users_profiles p
    INNER JOIN 
      users u
    ON
      u.user_uid = p.user_uid
    SET 
      p.user_fname = 'John', 
      p.user_lname = 'Doe', 
      p.user_gender = 'male'
    WHERE
      u.user_login = 'johndoe'
    AND
      u.user_uid = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE 
      users_profiles
      INNER JOIN 
          users
      ON
          users.user_uid = users_profiles.user_uid
    SET 
      users_profiles.user_fname = 'John', 
      users_profiles.user_lname = 'Doe', 
      users_profiles.user_gender = 'male'
    WHERE
      users.user_login = 'johndoe'
    AND
      users.user_uid = '11'
```

Comment: many thanks works perfectly, i accepted @StephanLechner answer on the basis he posted it first but thank you never the less.