# MySQL: Update Wordpress Custom Field Value by its WPML Language

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wpml

I have 4 languages on my site, and 50 posts per language. In each of the 200 posts there is a custom field with the current value

```
Monday
```

Now I would like to update this custom field for my other languages (German, French, Spanish) with their respective translations of the word 'Monday'. So for the 50 German posts, the current value 'Monday' would be updated to

```
Montag
```

For the 50 French posts the custom field value would become

```
Lundi
```

And, last not least, for the 50 Spanish posts, the custom field value needs to be

```
Lunes
```

Now, instead of opening 150 tabs in my browser and manually update the custom field values via WP Admin, I'd like to run a MySQL query for each language to bulk update the values.

The "logic" of the query to update my German posts' custom field value would look something like that:

```
UPDATE 'wp_postmeta'
SET 'meta_value' = 'Montag'
 WHERE 'meta_value' = 'Monday'
AND 
 FROM TABLE 'wp_icl_locale_map' WHERE 'code' = 'de'
```

This is not working due to syntax errors and I'm not a MySQL expert.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query).

Comment: I did a one hour google/stackoverflow search before posting my question but I didn't find anything - otherwise I would not have posted it in the first place. And I don't see the possible duplicity in your suggested link either.

Comment: The possible duplicate shows how to update one table based on values in other joined tables. Isn't that what your SQL is trying to do? Or are you trying to update two tables in the same statement?

Comment: It seems like JOIN may indeed be what I'm looking for. When I stumbled across this term for the first time, I assumed it would mean "merge" (tables) and quickly skipped it therefor. Mea culpa!

Comment: Ah, no problem. Let me know how you get on. I'll suggest it as a duplicate for now, but if you find it is not, please edit the question to describe how it is different. Thanks `:-)`.