# MYSQL: Help for fast update

Tags: mysql, sql

i need some help to get a fast update on my table in MySQL

```
Table 1     
id | value  
1    0  
2    0  
3    0 ...

Table 2  
t1_id | t2_id  
1       2  
1       3  
3       5 ...
```

Have about 150,000 rows in table 1, and about 1,3 million in table 2. I need set t1.value = 1 when t1.id exists in table 2.

```
update table1 t1, table2 t2
set value = 1
where t1.id = t2.id;
```

Without some distinct parameter, it will do many times for each id, making it slow to update all t1 rows.

Any help would be gladly accepted.

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query - using a JOIN might perform faster

Comment: thanks for you answer, but the join produces many entries for each value in table 1 too, so it will do that many update for each id, dont solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.value = 1
  FROM table_t1 t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM table_t2 t2 
                WHERE t2.id = t1.id
               )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I get an syntax error: 'from' is not valid input at this position

Comment: @Esteban P. without FROM line thats works great and in few seconds. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
update table1 
set value=1
from table2
where table1.id=table2.t1_id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, @Esteban P. solution works great !

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!