# Result-processing after SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables: `tb1`, `tb2`, `tb3`, `tb4`.

I want to return all the columns in 4 tables:

```
SELECT tb1.col1a, tb1.col1b, tb2.col2a, tb3.col3a, tb3.col3b, tb4.col4a
FROM tb1, 
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.col1a=tb2.col2a
INNER JOIN tb3 ON tb1.col1a=tb3.col3a
INNER JOIN tb4 ON tb3.col3a=tb4.col4a
```

The result is a new table, we'll call it be `tbX`.

Now, I want to update a column `col3b` of `tb3` with condition to base on `tbX`, what do I have to?

Comment: Read about `update set  ... from .. join ...`

Comment: btw the condition is not from tbx but from one of the joined tables. so it can be much easier to just join tb2 with the one that contains the data you want to use for update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) Perhaps 3 tables is enough when practicing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can update using CTE as below.
WITH TBX
AS
(
SELECT tb1.col1a,tb1.col1b,tb2.col2a,tb3.col3a,tb3.col3b,tb4.col4a
FROM tb1
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb1.col1a=tb2.col2a
INNER JOIN tb3 ON tb1.col1a=tb3.col3a
INNER JOIN tb4 ON tb3.col3a=tb4.col4a
)
UPDATE XYZ
SET XYZ.COLUMN = WHAT NEED TO BE REPLACED 
FROM XYZ
JOIN TBX
ON XYZ.COLNAME = TBX.COLNAME
```

Comment: thanks, but it's false. 
I go this query and result was  Unrecognized statement type