# MySQL introducing new column on existing table A and update data from table B

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I have an existing Table A with columns c1, c2, c3, c4, c5. I have another Table B with c1, c2, c3.

**Table A** (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, C6)

**Table B** (c1, c2, c3)

I want to introduce a new column in Table A c6 and dump data from Table B c3.

- Table A c2 and Table B c2 are userid's
- Table A c2 may have duplicates.

I also want to update insert c6 values for duplicates.

Please help me I wrote below query but it ran for 2 hours did nothing. Table A has 1 million records and Table B has 100 thousand records

I am using HeidiSQL tool to do this update. I was wondering if this is an issue with the tool?

```
UPDATE Table A
INNER JOIN Table B ON 
Table A.c2 = Table B.c2 
SET Table A.c6 = Table B.c3;
```

Comment: Your query should work... Try for few records with adding the where clause like "WHERE A.c2 = 1"

Comment: Mittal thanks for responding is working for few records but if I run for all the records it is taking long time.

Comment: Use explain on the query to see if it uses indexes for joining. Since you want to update 1 million records, it should take a while.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query) ?