# Merge duplicate records retaining some data based on conditional values in MySql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a peculiar dupes problem. I can identify the records easily enough, but I need to do what's essentially a merge on some accompanying data.

Here's the problem. My table is a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `People` (
  `PersonId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Forename` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FlagOne` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `FlagTwo` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `FlagThree` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`)
)
```

The duplicate records differ only in title and flag values - they are identified as duplicates by having identical address, forename and surname fields:

```
PersonId    Address         Title   Forename    Surname FlagOne FlagTwo FlagThree
1           6 Smith Street  Mrs     Jane        Doe     1       0       0
2           6 Smith Street  Ms      Jane        Doe     0       1       0
```

What I can't figure out how to do is amalgamate these two into a single record **which retains all the positive flags**. It doesn't matter which of the two original records is retained - using PersonId to differentiate them is fine. So, something like this is the desired result:

```
PersonId    Address         Title   Forename    Surname FlagOne FlagTwo FlagThree
2           6 Smith Street  Ms      Jane        Doe     1       1       0
```

I know how to do an update based on a join, but I'm not sure how to implement the condiationals needed to get this particular result?

Comment: `I can identify the records easily enough,`  .... How you know those are duplicated rows? `person_id` are differents

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In this instance, any record that has the same address, forename and surname is treated as a duplicate

Comment: Can the deduped records be placed into a new copy of the table? Or is part of your requirement to UPDATE some rows and DELETE others from the existing table?  I suspect the former will be easier.  Related question: do you need to preserve existing `PersonId` values?

Comment: Do you want to always keep the higher PersonID like your example ?

Comment: @DanielE. No, it doesn't matter which record gets kept.

Comment: @O.Jones No, we need to update and delete. This table is colossal - hundreds of millions of records, so I'll have to do it incrementally but that's a different problem. We do need to preserve existing PersonId values, yes, but it doesn't matter which one out of a dupe set gets kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you know how update with a JOIN, so something like this give the merge:

```
 SELECT MAX(PersonId),
        Address,
        MAX(Title), 
        Forename,
        Surname
        MAX( FlagOne ),
        MAX( FlagTwo ), 
        MAX( FlagThree)
FROM People
GROUP BY Address,
         Forename,
         Surname
```

Then you need to delete the duplicates

```
DELETE People
WHERE PersonID IN (SELECT MIN(PersonId)
                   FROM People
                   GROUP BY Address,
                            Forename,
                            Surname
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

this assume only duplicates, if you have three rows with same Forename, Surname. Will need a different aproach.

Comment: Thanks for this - silly of me not think of using MAX. FYI there are a few instances where this issue spans 3+ rows, but they can be left in situ. The issue doesn't actually impact functionality, just storage space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do it in 2 steps :

1- Update de the values :

```
Update People p
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(PersonId) as PId,
            Address,
            MAX(Title) as title, 
            Forename,
            Surname
            MAX( FlagOne ) as FlagOne,
            MAX( FlagTwo ) as FlagTwo, 
            MAX( FlagThree) as Flagthree
    FROM People
    GROUP BY Address,
             Forename,
             Surname ) t

 ON t.Address = p.Address
AND t.Forename = p.Forename
AND t.Surname = p.Surname
SET p.FlagOne = t.FlagOne , 
    p.FlagTwo = t.FlagTwo , 
    p.FlagThree= t.FlagThree
WHERE p.PersonId = t.PId
```

2- Delete :

```
DELETE p
 FROM People p
 INNER JOIN 
    People t ON t.Address = p.Address
                  AND t.Forename = p.Forename
                  AND t.Surname = p.Surname
 WHERE p.PersonId < t.PersonId
```

Comment: Daniel you don t need permision to update your question. If you see something missing just fix it

Comment: I think the `JOIN` sintaxis is wrong, and you miss the `ON` condition. You need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Comment: Your Delete statement work great for more than two duplicates. But you dont need `LEFT JOIN` use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: You are right for the delete INNER JOIN will work better. (i delete some comments )