# mySQL: Where should i put my WHERE?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a WHERE clause.
How should i manage it?

This is my Query:

```
UPDATE  usr_time_reg
JOIN users  ON usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment;
```

I'm trying to add: `WHERE usr_time_reg.usr_emplyoment = "Övrigt"`

I've tried:

```
UPDATE usr_time_reg
JOIN users  ON usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr, 
usr_time_reg.usr_employment = "Övrigt"
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment;

UPDATE usr_time_reg
JOIN users ON usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment
WHERE usr_time_reg.usr_employment = "Övrigt";

UPDATE usr_time_reg
JOIN users ON usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr
WHERE usr_time_reg.usr_employment = "Övrigt"
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment;

UPDATE usr_time_reg
JOIN users ON usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr
AND usr_time_reg.usr_emplyment = "Övrigt"
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment;
```

Comment: UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...

Comment: Your first proposal is ok, you just need to put the keyword WHERE in front of it.

Comment: more information on [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) website

Comment: @tangoal I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE usr_time_reg.usr_employment = "Övrigt" SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment =' at line 3

Comment: Your third query looks correct to me.  Did you try running it?  Did you [read this answer before you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query) ?

Comment: I guess that the Syntax error has nothing to do with the placement of the WHERE. But I don't see any syntax error at the moment. Ok, I'm on my phone and I might oversee something.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i get this error: Column 'usr_time_nr' in on clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below as it missing table reference in `ON`

```
UPDATE usr_time_reg
JOIN users ON users.usr_time_nr = usr_time_reg.usr_time_nr
SET usr_time_reg.usr_employment = users.employment
WHERE usr_time_reg.usr_employment = "Övrigt";
```

With `JOIN`

```
UPDATE usr_time_reg as tr, users as ur
SET tr.usr_employment = ur.employment
WHERE ur.usr_time_nr = tr.usr_time_nr and tr.usr_employment = "Övrigt";
```

While joining tables add table alias before field name to avoid `ambiguous column` error

Comment: Thank you! Works very well!

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work:

```
UPDATE usr_time_reg u1
INNER JOIN users u2
    ON u1.usr_time_nr = u2.usr_time_nr
SET u1.usr_employment = u2.employment;
WHERE u1.usr_emplyment = 'Övrigt';
```

It can be difficult to keep track of update join syntax for MySQL, in addition to other databases you might be using.  So it's always a good idea to have a [good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query) to use in case you forget.

The main change I made, other than using correct syntax, was to introduce table aliases to the update query.  In addition to making it a lot easier to read, it also resolved one of your errors regarding an ambiguous column reference to `user_time_nr`.  Now, it is clear to which table we are referring when we use that column.