# Queries are not work properly .Insert query is work fine but other three queries are not working it was occurred errors

Tags: php, mysql

I was create a form with four buttons such as submit,update,delete and search.insert query is work fine but other three queries are not working it was occurred errors.

**update**

Error: UPDATE FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curricular_activities WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID AND Student_ID=IM/20xx/002
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curr' at line 1

**search**

error:   result error

**delete**

Error: DELETE FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curricular_activities WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID AND course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID AND Student_ID=IM/20xx/002
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND course_det' at line 1

Here is my files

**Form.php**

```html
<?php

    $profile_picture=$_POST['profile_picture'];//define variables 
    $student_id=$_POST['student_id'];
    $admitted_date=$_POST['admitted_date'];
    $academic_year=$_POST['academic_year'];
    $course=$_POST['course'];

    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];//define variables
    $middle_name=$_POST['middle_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $dob=$_POST['dob'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $nic=$_POST['nic'];
    $nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
    $religion=$_POST['religion'];
    $race=$_POST['race'];

    $p_add_line1=$_POST['p_add_line1'];//define variables
    $p_add_line2=$_POST['p_add_line2'];
    $p_add_line3=$_POST['p_add_line3'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $t_add_line1=$_POST['t_add_line1'];
    $t_add_line2=$_POST['t_add_line2'];
    $t_add_line3=$_POST['t_add_line3'];
    $stu_con_home=$_POST['stu_con_home'];
    $stu_con_mobile1=$_POST['stu_con_mobile1'];
    $stu_con_mobile2=$_POST['stu_con_mobile2'];
    $p_con_home=$_POST['p_con_home'];
    $p_con_mobile1=$_POST['p_con_mobile1'];
    $p_con_mobile2=$_POST['p_con_mobile2'];

    $o_admi_no=$_POST['o_admi_no'];//define variables
    $o_year=$_POST['o_year'];
    $o_subject1=$_POST['o_subject1'];
    $o_grade1=$_POST['o_grade1'];
    $o_subject2=$_POST['o_subject2'];
    $o_grade2=$_POST['o_grade2'];
    $o_subject3=$_POST['o_subject3'];
    $o_grade3=$_POST['o_grade3'];
    $o_subject4=$_POST['o_subject4'];
    $o_grade4=$_POST['o_grade4'];
    $o_subject5=$_POST['o_subject5'];
    $o_grade5=$_POST['o_grade5'];
    $o_subject6=$_POST['o_subject6'];
    $o_grade6=$_POST['o_grade6'];
    $o_subject7=$_POST['o_subject7'];
    $o_grade7=$_POST['o_grade7'];
    $o_subject8=$_POST['o_subject8'];
    $o_grade8=$_POST['o_grade8'];
    $o_subject9=$_POST['o_subject9'];
    $o_grade9=$_POST['o_grade9'];

    $a_admi_no=$_POST['a_admi_no'];//define variables
    $a_year=$_POST['a_year'];
    $a_subject1=$_POST['a_subject1'];
    $a_grade1=$_POST['a_grade1'];
    $a_subject2=$_POST['a_subject2'];
    $a_grade2=$_POST['a_grade2'];
    $a_subject3=$_POST['a_subject3'];
    $a_grade3=$_POST['a_grade3'];
    $a_subject4=$_POST['a_subject4'];
    $a_grade4=$_POST['a_grade4'];
    $z_score=$_POST['z_score'];

    $school_level=$_POST['school_level'];//define variables
    $zonal_level=$_POST['zonal_level'];
    $district_level=$_POST['district_level'];
    $provincial_level=$_POST['provincial_level'];
    $national_level=$_POST['national_level'];
    $international_level=$_POST['international_level'];
    $current_activities=$_POST['current_activities'];

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","student_information");//create connection

    //Test Connection
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed :".$connection->connect_error);
    }

    //Create insert query
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO course_details (Student_ID,Admitted_Date,Academic_Year,Course,Profile_Picture)
            VALUES ('$student_id','$admitted_date','$academic_year','$course','$profile_picture');";

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO personal_details (Student_ID,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,DOB,Gender,NIC,Nationality,Religion,Race)
            VALUES ('$student_id','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$dob','$gender','$nic','$nationality','$religion','$race');";

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO contact_details (Student_ID,P_Add_Line1,P_Add_Line2,P_Add_Line3,City,Email,T_Add_Line1,T_Add_Line2,T_Add_Line3,stu_con_home,Stu_Con_Mobile1,Stu_Con_Mobile2,P_Con_Home,P_Con_Mobile1,P_Con_Mobile2)
            VALUES ('$student_id','$p_add_line1','$p_add_line2','$p_add_line3','$city','$email','$t_add_line1','$t_add_line2','$t_add_line3','$stu_con_home','$stu_con_mobile1','$stu_con_mobile2','$p_con_home','$p_con_mobile1','$p_con_mobile2');";
      
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO academic_details (Student_ID,O_Admi_No,O_Year,O_Subject1,O_Grade1,O_Subject2,O_Grade2,O_Subject3,O_Grade3,O_Subject4,O_Grade4,O_Subject5,O_Grade5,O_Subject6,O_Grade6,O_Subject7,O_Grade7,O_Subject8,O_Grade8,O_Subject9,O_Grade9,A_Admi_No,A_Year,A_Subject1,A_Grade1,A_Subject2,A_Grade2,A_Subject3,A_Grade3,A_Subject4,A_Grade4,Z_Score)
            VALUES ('$student_id','$o_admi_no','$o_year','$o_subject1','$o_grade1','$o_subject2','$o_grade2','$o_subject3','$o_grade3','$o_subject4','$o_grade4','$o_subject5','$o_grade5','$o_subject6','$o_grade6','$o_subject7','$o_grade7','$o_subject8','$o_grade8','$o_subject9','$o_grade9','$a_admi_no','$a_year','$a_subject1','$a_grade1','$a_subject2','$a_grade2','$a_subject3','$a_grade3','$a_subject4','$a_grade4','$z_score');";      

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO extra_curricular_activities (Student_ID,School_Level,Zonal_Level,District_Level,Provincial_Level,National_Level,International_Level,Current_Activities)
            VALUES ('$student_id','$school_level','$zonal_level','$district_level','$provincial_level','$national_level','$international_level','$current_activities')";

        //Test insert query
        if ($connection->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Submitted Successsfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        }
    }

    //create update query
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $sql ="UPDATE FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curricular_activities WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID AND Student_ID=$student_id";

        if ($connection->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Updated Successsfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        }
    }

    //create delete query
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $sql ="DELETE FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curricular_activities WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID AND Student_ID=$student_id";

        if ($connection->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Deleted Successsfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        }
    }

    //create search query
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $sql ="SELECT course_details.*,personal_details.*,contact_details.*,academic_details.*,extra_curricular_activities.* FROM course_details,personal_details,contact_details,academic_details,extra_curricular_activities WHERE course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID AND
            course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID AND Student_ID=$student_id";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        if ($result) 
        {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) 
            {
                while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $profile_picture=$rows['profile_picture'];
                    $student_id=$rows['student_id'];
                    $admitted_date=$rows['admitted_date'];
                    $academic_year=$rows['academic_year'];
                    $course=$rows['course'];

                    $first_name=$rows['first_name'];
                    $middle_name=$rows['middle_name'];
                    $last_name=$rows['last_name'];
                    $dob=$rows['dob'];
                    $gender=$rows['gender'];
                    $nic=$rows['nic'];
                    $nationality=$rows['nationality'];
                    $religion=$rows['religion'];
                    $race=$rows['race'];

                    $p_add_line1=$rows['p_add_line1'];
                    $p_add_line2=$rows['p_add_line2'];
                    $p_add_line3=$rows['p_add_line3'];
                    $city=$rows['city'];
                    $email=$rows['email'];
                    $t_add_line1=$rows['t_add_line1'];
                    $t_add_line2=$rows['t_add_line2'];
                    $t_add_line3=$rows['t_add_line3'];
                    $stu_con_home=$rows['stu_con_home'];
                    $stu_con_mobile1=$rows['stu_con_mobile1'];
                    $stu_con_mobile2=$rows['stu_con_mobile2'];
                    $p_con_home=$rows['p_con_home'];
                    $p_con_mobile1=$rows['p_con_mobile1'];
                    $p_con_mobile2=$rows['p_con_mobile2'];

                    $o_admi_no=$rows['o_admi_no'];
                    $o_year=$rows['o_year'];
                    $o_subject1=$rows['o_subject1'];
                    $o_grade1=$rows['o_grade1'];
                    $o_subject2=$rows['o_subject2'];
                    $o_grade2=$rows['o_grade2'];
                    $o_subject3=$rows['o_subject3'];
                    $o_grade3=$rows['o_grade3'];
                    $o_subject4=$rows['o_subject4'];
                    $o_grade4=$rows['o_grade4'];
                    $o_subject5=$rows['o_subject5'];
                    $o_grade5=$rows['o_grade5'];
                    $o_subject6=$rows['o_subject6'];
                    $o_grade6=$rows['o_grade6'];
                    $o_subject7=$rows['o_subject7'];
                    $o_grade7=$rows['o_grade7'];
                    $o_subject8=$rows['o_subject8'];
                    $o_grade8=$rows['o_grade8'];
                    $o_subject9=$rows['o_subject9'];
                    $o_grade9=$rows['o_grade9'];

                    $a_admi_no=$rows['a_admi_no'];
                    $a_year=$rows['a_year'];
                    $a_subject1=$rows['a_subject1'];
                    $a_grade1=$rows['a_grade1'];
                    $a_subject2=$rows['a_subject2'];
                    $a_grade2=$rows['a_grade2'];
                    $a_subject3=$rows['a_subject3'];
                    $a_grade3=$rows['a_grade3'];
                    $a_subject4=$rows['a_subject4'];
                    $a_grade4=$rows['a_grade4'];
                    $z_score=$rows['z_score'];

                    $school_level=$rows['school_level'];
                    $zonal_level=$rows['zonal_level'];
                    $district_level=$rows['district_level'];
                    $provincial_level=$rows['provincial_level'];
                    $national_level=$rows['national_level'];
                    $international_level=$rows['international_level'];
                    $current_activities=$rows['current_activities'];
                }
            }else{
                echo ("No data are available");
            }
        }else{
            echo ("result error");
        }
    }
    //print_r($_POST);

    $connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: Several issues here. FROM after UPDATE is incorrect syntax. You can also not specify different tables in a comma separated format in your delete, update and select statements. Just look up correct syntax for selecting from multiple tables and apply those rules to your deletes and updates as well.

Comment: what are those?I can't figure it out..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your variable $student_id in quotes to convert this Student_ID=IM/20xx/002 into this Student_ID='IM/20xx/002' and make your query valid.

Anyway, I'd recommend to use the native MySQL/MariaDB functions (provided by the PDO PHP extension) to escape your query values and avoid security issues. Also the binding of values can be done with those functions.

Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Are my queries incorrect?How can I create queries for multiple tables?

Comment: Yes, the incorrect part is where the string is not enclosed between quotes.
Here Student_ID=$student_id you are generating this: Student_ID=IM/20xx/002. You should put quotes around your variable. That would be a quick workaround for your code, but I'd recommend you to use the binding functions that PDO provides.
You can simply enclose the $student_id between quotes if you are sure the IDs won't have special SQL characters.

Comment: I correct that problem.but the same errors were occurred.

Comment: $sql ="UPDATE course_details
   JOIN personal_details ON course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID
   JOIN contact_details ON course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID
   JOIN academic_details ON course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID 
   JOIN extra_curricular_activities ON course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID
   SET course_details.Student_ID ='$student_id'";

Comment: this is correct except for the last part of update. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your query.

First, notice this code `Student_ID=$student_id` at the end of `SELECT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`. The php part should be enclosed so it will look like this. `Student_ID='$student_id'`

Second, there is no `FROM` in `UPDATE` query. Remove it.

Third, this is the most fatal one. Again, notice this code `Student_ID=$student_id` at the end of `SELECT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`. Since these three queries include all 5 tables and each of the tables have the same field `Student_ID`, there is no way the queries will know which `Student_ID` belongs to. Put one of the tables before the field.

After the errors are fixed, the end of `SELECT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` queries should look like this `course_details.Student_ID='$student_id'`.

For the `course_details` one, you can replace with any table as long as the table have the `Student_ID` field.

**NOTE**

You can improve these three queries using `INNER JOIN`. It is much more effective than put all of the tables after `FROM`.

**EDIT**

Here is the improved query for `SELECT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`.

SELECT

```
SELECT course_details.*, personal_details.*, contact_details.*, academic_details.*, extra_curricular_activities.*
FROM course_details
INNER JOIN personal_details ON course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN contact_details ON course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN academic_details ON course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN extra_curricular_activities ON course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID
WHERE course_details.Student_ID='$student_id'
```

UPDATE

```
UPDATE course_details
INNER JOIN personal_details ON course_details.Student_ID =personal_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN contact_details ON course_details.Student_ID =contact_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN academic_details ON course_details.Student_ID =academic_details.Student_ID
INNER JOIN extra_curricular_activities ON course_details.Student_ID =extra_curricular_activities.Student_ID
SET ... (there is no set in your post so i don't know which field that needs to be updated)
WHERE course_details.Student_ID='$student_id'
```

DELETE

For this query, I break it into five queries.

```
DELETE FROM course_details WHERE Student_ID='$student_id';
DELETE FROM personal_details WHERE Student_ID='$student_id';
DELETE FROM contact_details WHERE Student_ID='$student_id';
DELETE FROM academic_details WHERE Student_ID='$student_id';
DELETE FROM extra_curricular_activities WHERE Student_ID='$student_id';
```

Comment: can you give me an example for that..I know use it for two tables.but I have 5 tables how can I write query for five tables