# SQL Update One Table If Record Does Not Exist In Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     invoices i
     ON i.customer_id = c.id
WHERE i.customer_id IS NULL
```

The above works to give me all the customer accounts that have no invoices.  It takes a long time to run, but I'm not concerned with the speed.  I will likely only run this a couple times a year.

What I can't get right is updating a record in the customers table when the account has no invoices.  I have tried a number of different ways to accomplish this but always get a syntax error.

One attempt is below...

```
UPDATE c
    SET active=0
    FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
         invoices i
         ON i.customer_id = c.id
    WHERE i.customer_id IS NULL
```

I get a syntax error in the Join when I try to run this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE customers c LEFT JOIN
       invoices i
       ON i.customer_id = c.id
    SET active = 0  
WHERE i.customer_id IS NULL;
```

The use of `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` is rather database-specific.  For instance, MySQL doesn't support the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` (SQL Server and Postgres do).

Standard syntax that should work in any database is:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET active = 0
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoices i WHERE i.customer_id = customers.id);
```

Answer (score 3):

You just made little mistake below query will work

```
    UPDATE customers  c         
    LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.customer_id = c.id
    SET active=0
    WHERE i.customer_id IS NULL
```